# Contribution, and the way thereof, of the core 6p orbitals of compounds of plutonium(VIII)

Tags: molecular-structure, molecular-orbital-theory, theoretical-chemistry, transition-metals, magnetism

According to the [NIST database](https://physics.nist.gov/cgi-bin/ASD/ie.pl?spectra=Pu&submit=Retrieve+Data&units=1&format=0&order=0&at_num_out=on&ion_charge_out=on&el_name_out=on&shells_out=on&conf_out=on&ion_conf_out=on&e_out=0&unc_out=on&biblio=on), the ground-state configuration of plutonium(VIII) is [Hg]5f³6p³, when intuitively it should be the same as neutral radon([Hg]6p⁶). Since plutonium(VIII) compounds are already known, there are two problems:

1. the plutonium(VIII) cation is paramagnetic;
2. the core 6p shell of plutonium must, according to this electronic configuration, take part in bonding in compounds of plutonium(VIII).

Are there any plutonium(VIII) complexes with diamagnetic ligands known to be (experimentally or theoretically) paramagnetic or with meaningful contributions (of the central plutonium's 6p shell) in its bonding?

Comment: N.B. the same problem occurs for neptunium(VII); https://physics.nist.gov/cgi-bin/ASD/ie.pl?spectra=Np&submit=Retrieve+Data&units=1&format=0&order=0&at_num_out=on&ion_charge_out=on&el_name_out=on&shells_out=on&conf_out=on&ion_conf_out=on&e_out=0&unc_out=on&biblio=on

Comment: Cation and compound are two different things - such configuration, even if correct (probably not) isn't enough to say that 6p orbitals would have significant contribution to bonds.

Comment: It's rather 6d orbitals that do have https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plutonium#Electronic_structure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is actually some question about the existence of plutonium(VIII). [Huang et al. [1]](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/acs.inorgchem.5b01540) investigate the electronic structure and stability of nominal Pu(VIII) oxide and fluoride complexes. They find that in all cases studied, either the proposed compound decomposes with loss of fluorine or oxygen, or in more oxide-rich cases the most stable conformation has two of the oxygen atoms forming a superoxo ligand and the plutonium thereby only in oxidation state +5. Pu(VIII) conformations of $\ce{PuO4, PuO3F2, PuO2F4, PuO2F5^-}$ are metastable with the corresponding Pu(V) superoxide-containing conformations being fully stable.

Regardless of oxidation state, all molecules and conformations show the $6p$ orbitals completely filled and bonding from the normal plutonium valence orbitals instead; no significant bonding with the $6p$ orbitals is indicated. The Pu(VIII) conformations are rendered most stable as as spin singlets, consistent with the conventional radon-core model.

One reason for the noted gas-phase electronic structure is that multiple subshells in plutonium have energy levels close to one another and thus what are normally secondary factors may come into play. With bare Pu(VIII), $5f^36p^3$ could be favored over the expected $6p^6$ by exchange energy of the unpaired electrons in the $5f$ and $6p$ orbitals. However, loss of unpaired electrons in the complexes could be expected because the bonding to ligands may drive electron pairing, as it does in many other examples involving the metal in high oxidation states.

**Reference**

1. Wei Huang, Pekka Pyykkö, and Jun Li (2015). "Is Octavalent Pu(VIII) Possible? Mapping the Plutonium Oxyfluoride Series PuOnF8–2n (n = 0–4)". *Inorg. Chem.* **54**(17), 8825–8831. https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/acs.inorgchem.5b01540.